# SQL Server : how to get specific column from stored procedure without modifying it

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

Here is the sample stored procedure

```
DECLARE @ReturnTable TABLE (DateTime DATETIME,      
                            WrongUSSD VARCHAR(30),
                            AllMSISDN INT,      
                            UniqueMSISDN INT,   
                            SubscriptionActivated INT)

SELECT * 
FROM @ReturnTable
```

Modification in stored procedure is not allowed, I just need specific column form this procedure by select statement.

I have tried this

```
select WrongUSSD 
FROM openrowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver={SQL SERVER}; Server=server_name;UID=user; PWD=pass;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC [DatabaseName].[dbo].[ProcedureName] "2016-01-01","2016-04-01"') as a
```

This method doesn't work if the is link server exists in stored procedure

Is there any other method?? Please help

Comment: Why do you need it to only return one column?

Answer (score 1):

Using temp table:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC [dbo].[ProcedureName]

SELECT WrongUSSD
FROM #TempTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yes it works but the problem is I have lots of stored procedure from which I have to fetch column, have to create lots of temporary table(almost 50-60 temporary table). Is thre any other methods??

Comment: I have also got the problem with temporary table is nested insert, there are already lots of insert query in stored procedure, so nested insert is creating the issues